# Atlassian SDK error: can not install plugin

Tags: jira-plugin, mojo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I doing the following steps:

1. Install Atlassian latest SDK 5.1.18
2. Run Atlassian command: atlas-run-standalone --product jira. Then I can access the web.
3. Go to sample plugin folder and execute: "altas-cli:. then "pi".

This is the output error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.run(ExecuteGoalCommand.java:112)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.run(ExecuteGoalCommand.java:107)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.CliShell.interpretCommand(CliShell.java:48)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.CliShell.run(CliShell.java:29)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.AbstractCliMojo.displayShell(AbstractCliMojo.java:174)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.AbstractCliMojo.access$000(AbstractCliMojo.java:22)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.AbstractCliMojo$1.run(AbstractCliMojo.java:123)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
    at org.shaded.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.shaded.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor$ExecutionEnvironmentM3.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:476)
    at org.shaded.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.MojoCall.run(MojoCall.java:33)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.runMojo(ExecuteGoalCommand.java:126)
    at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.run(ExecuteGoalCommand.java:109)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:106)
    at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.MavenGoals.copyBundledDependencies(MavenGoals.java:142)
    at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.CopyBundledDependenciesMojo.execute(CopyBundledDependenciesMojo.java:15)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.shaded.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:172)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:89)
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:104)
    ... 15 more
```

please help me.

Jira sample plugin: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/jira-gadget-2
(I succeeded installing this Gadget once)

Comment: can you share code in pom.xml  file

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure if Your Jira SDK version(amps.version) and Jira version specified in pom.xml are same as installed in system.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <amps.version>5.1.11</amps.version>
    <jira.version>6.3.14</jira.version>
</properties>
```

And please add Your pom.xml to question as Ram wrote
(I cannot add comments so I add answer)